# Among -newermt and -mtime options for find command which one is faster for large inputs?

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to find files older than a specific number of days in a directory (sub directories included).

So for this purpose I was using find command, and would like to know if there is any performance advantage for once option (-mtime and -newermt)  over the other with find command?

Comment: If one is consistently faster for a small set of inputs it's going to be faster for a large set of inputs.

Comment: What amount of data? What have you noticed so far regarding the performance of both  options?

Comment: File numbers will be in millions . And directories in 1000's . I was using mtime only yet and it is taking very long time (hours) . And -newermt I have not used yet . So need to know if there is any advantage with this option .